# Não consigo fazer delete com PHP, MySQL

Tags: php

Então, sou iniciante em PHP e estou com uma dúvida no seguinte codigo...
quando eu clico no botao de remover ele nao remove apenas o id da volta do while, ele remove todos, alguem poderia me ajudar?

```
<?php
    include 'conexao.php';
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>CRUD - ALUNOS</h1>
        <form action="FrmCadastro.php" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="+"/>
        </form>
        <table border="2px">
        <th>Aluno</th>
        <th>Nota</th>
        <th>Turma</th>
        <tr></tr>
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * from tbAluno";
            $listarAlunos = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listarAlunos)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $nome = $row['aluno'];
                $nota = $row['nota'];
                $turma = $row['turma'];
        ?>
            <td>
                <?php echo"$nome"?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo"$nota"?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo"$turma"?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form>
                <input type="submit" value="remover"/>
                    <?php
                        $sql = "DELETE from tbAluno WHERE id = $id";
                        $removerAluno = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
                        echo $id;
                    ?>
                </form>
            </td>
            <tr></tr>
        <?php 
            }
        ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: O código de DELETE está sendo executado para cada usuário que você selecionou, na query. Para fazer com que o código seja executado apenas quando clicar o botão, você precisaria fazer um handling do formulário

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage.php

```
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
              <td>
                <a href="delet.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <?php } ?>
```

Delet.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM table WHERE id='$id'");
$result  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

header("Location: manage.php");
exit();
```

Basta replicar o código de acordo com suas informações e finalidade, fiz apenas uma demonstração.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente e eu consegui entender o código. Obrigado novamente!